# jQueryMobile and toggling DIV visibility

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I've got strange behaviour and I can't realize how to fix it.

I've got mobile version of web service and on every page I'm placing search form in `DIV` element, whole container should be toggled with common jQuery's [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

The code is (script is placed directly in page's code, like in the sample):

```html
<div id="search-area" style="display: none">
    search form here...
</div>

<a href="#" id="search-area-switch" data-role="button">Search</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#search-area-switch').live('tap',function (event) {
        $('#search-area').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that `toggle()` works only on the **first** page after reload and after next page change toggling is not possible anymore. (BTW. pages are loaded with AJAX to keep transitions etc.)

What did I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script is in the head of the page it won't be run when you change pages, since Jquery Mobile ignores the head after the first page.

In general, having multiple items with the same id is bad practice.  It's better to make them each the same class and then have your selector find the items that way.

Comment: Nope, it's not in header, as I wrote I placed it in the page's code (inside div with `data-role="page"`), will try with different IDs

Comment: Having different IDs should stop the problem.  The other divs with the identical ids are still hanging around when you change pages, and so JQuery defaults to picking the first one, which isn't the one you want.

Comment: Yeap, you're right, what's more as my JS is generated in the controller I can modify each instance to work with selected ID (and don't need to rely on the same class). Thanks saved me lot of time.