# Toggle function on pageinit : jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to toggle a list with a button that is located in the header of my JQM site.

This code is working only when the page first loads.  Once I load another page, the toggle function is being ignored (though if I put an alert in, that seems to work).

I have included the script inside the `data-role="page"` element.

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function (){
    $("#trigger-menu").toggle(function(e) {
          $("ul#menu-list").show();
          //change icon here
          e.preventDefault();
    }, function(e) {
          $("ul#menu-list").hide();
          //change icon here
          e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Is 'pageinit' the appropriate event to use in this instance?
I am using JQM 1.2.0

Comment: Have you tried .on() instead of .bind? I'm not sure if it works the same way in JQM, but I would go with the non-deprecated method, and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you described is the expected one for the **pageinit** event, which occurs only once per page.

If you want to toggle your list on every page transition, after animations have completed, I suggest you use the **pageshow** event:

```
$('div').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
    alert('This page was just hidden: '+ ui.prevPage);
});
```

For more details, please take a look at the jQuery mobile events documentation [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I had tried this, and it also does not work.  Same behaviour as above.  First instance works a treat, then all following ignore the toggle function.

Comment: I've set up an example to show how to use the **pageshow** event properly: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVypq/2/. Maybe you are not getting the result you want because you are not using the toggle function the right way. See [these examples](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

Comment: Did some more digging and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529645/jquerymobile-and-toggling-div-visibility, looks like it was my use of IDs instead of classes